# How to change height of google map programmatically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

[image]

I have 1 view in my Angular / Ionic app. When the view initially loads, the div display Google Maps is set to height:1px so it can't be seen. When the user clicks, the div's height gets set to the height of the window. However, when I run this, while it looks like the entire div is spanning the entire window, I'm only able to see a portion of the map.

If I hardcode the height to some number, say 1000px, then the div shows up at that size and the complete map renders. But I want to show it conditionally.

Any advice on how to fix this?

View:

```
<div id = "map" data-tap-disabled="true" style = "height: {{height_of_map}}px;"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.height_of_map = 1; //Initial height of window on load (it's essentially hidden on load)

//Height should change when getMap function gets called
$scope.getMap = function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    $scope.height_of_map = window.innerHeight;
    console.log($scope.height_of_map); //logs the correct height of window

  }
```

Rest of Google maps code:

```
[![$scope.initialise = function() {
          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.758446, -122.411789);
          var markersArray = \[\];

          //Initial settings for the map
          var mapOptions = {
                  center: myLatlng,
                  zoom: 2,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                  styles: \[{ featureType: "poi", elementType: "labels", stylers: \[{ visibility: "off" }\]}\]

              };

          //Load the initial map
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); 

          //Event listener to add a marker      
          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
            clearOverlays();
            placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
            $scope.coordinates = e.latLng;
            localStorage.userLat = $scope.coordinates.lat();
            localStorage.userLong = $scope.coordinates.lng();
          });

          //Actual function to add a marker
          function placeMarker(position, map) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: position,
              map: map
            });
            map.panTo(position);
            markersArray.push(marker);
          }

          function clearOverlays() {
            for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
              markersArray\[i\].setMap(null);
            }
            markersArray.length = 0;
          }

          // $scope.map=map;

    };
    // End of initialise

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $scope.initialise);][1]][1]
```

In the image attached, I'm able to pan around the white space below the map because I believe it is still technically the map, but I'm not able to see any of it.

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: maps has a rezize() method ... see api reference docs

Comment: I tried reading through the docs but I'm not sure where to place the resize() method. Can you provide an example? When I add google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); below the domlistener event I currently have, nothing happens.

Comment: since need a digest for the new height to be set on div, put it inside `$timeout` after set height. Your log is right height, but angular digest hasn't occurred probably ... `$timeout` will fire after digest

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you have a code example?

Comment: All this should really be in a directive ... window load event isn't really practical with angular

Comment: Code example for what you would do?

Comment: @charlietfl is right - add a `$timeout(function() { google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize") })`  as the last part of your `$scope.initialise()` function.